# My Opencart Admin->Catalog->Product page not working

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart-3

I have developed an opencart based ecommerce website.I have also purchased journal theme for the web. It had been working fine for 5 months. But suddenly my home page stopped rendering & even the admin panel's product page started showing the same internal http 500 error. After some research and provided solutions from github I was then able to retrieve my home page rendering up. But still the admin->catalog->product page shows the same error. On enabling error codes, I got the following error:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): (HY001/1038): Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size in /home/acmysys1/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 19

I also tried to contact my web host and requested him to increase my server sort buffer size, but he refused to do so as I was having an shared ip. Cant afford to purchase a new VPS host. Also tried to connect to putty through ssh but connection always gets refused. Everything rather than the product page seems to be working fine.

Can anyone please suggest what to do because I am in a vast dilemma over it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any product related extensions/mods you can try disabling, as it maybe some poor performing code that is causing error. I would not think working code would hit this limit.

If you want to track down the  you can just start "debugging" the code to find the step that "breaks" it and causes your error:

Im not up on v3 but in v2 admin product pages list/add/edit are generated by admin/controller/catalog/product.php
But your problems are most likely in admin/model/catalog/product.php getProducts() function. try commenting out the ORDER BY lines, to see if not sorting your products as a test prevents the error and lets you view them.

Bear in mind with modification system it might be running out of system/storage/modification/admin instead, so check there first for your file and test edit there to avoid having to refresh mods button every time. Just put in a 'echo "hello";' to check your changes are having effect.